# Method params match signature, but still getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameter-passing, method-signature

I am in the midst of converting a VB library to C#. One of my methods has the following signature in VB:

```
Private Shared Sub FillOrder(ByVal row As DataRowView, ByRef o As Order)
```

In C# I converted it to:

```
private static void FillOrder(DataRowView row, ref Order o)
```

From my constructor inside my `Order` class, I am calling the `FillOrder()` method like so:

```
DataView dv = //[get the data]
if (dv.Count > 0)
{
    FillOrder(dv[0], this);
}
```

In VB, this works:

```
Dim dv As DataView = '[get data]'
If dv.Count > 0 Then
    FillOrder(dv.Item(0), Me)
End If
```

However, in VS10 in the C# file I am getting a red squiggle under this call with the following error:

> The best overloaded method match for [the method] has some invalid arguments

This was working code in VB. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wonder how could it work: `this` should be readonly, right? So you shouldn't be able to have `ref this`.

Comment: In C# you don't need to add the `ref` keyword for the `Order` parameter. It is a reference type and you probably don't need to pass it by ref.

Comment: @Oded: What? There's no difference between `ref` and `ByRef`.

Comment: Unless you can give a good explanation, you shouldn't be using a `ref` parameter in the first place.

Comment: @slaks what is wrong w/using a `ref` param?

Comment: @Jason: `ref this` is bad, `this` is read-only.

Comment: No, you (probably) don't need a `ref` parameter.  Why do you think you need a `ref` parameter?

Comment: passing using `ref` means that the method can change what the variable passed in is pointing to. That doesn't make a lot of sense in this situation. Just remove `ref` and you should be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the second parameter as `ref`.
However, you cannot pass `this` as `ref` ([unless it's a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)), so you'll need a temporary variable.

Note that the parameter almost definitely shouldn't be `ref` in the first place.

Comment: But is the `ref` in the translation really needed?

Comment: @Vlad: Not for structs.  @Oded: For the parameter, yes.  For the argument, no.

Comment: thanks for the help. i need the ref param, but i overloaded the method to have it the way i do and another without the `ref`

Comment: @Jason: **Why** do you think you need a `ref` parameter?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eek064h4.aspx), `ByRef` in VB for reference types is not the same as `ref` in C#. It rather means that the function may change the variable.

So, just drop `ref` from the function definition:

```
private static void FillOrder(DataRowView row, Order o)
```

BTW, is your `Order` a `class` or a `struct`?

Comment: `Order` is a class. I need the `ref` call, so I overloaded `FillOrder()` and got everything working correctly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: **Wrong**. `ByRef` and `ref` are the same.

Comment: @Jason: why do you need `ref`? Do you replace `o` inside of the function?

Comment: @SLaks: **proof**? (If they really were the same, one couldn't pass `this` as `ByRef`.)

Comment: @Vlad: VB degrades to pass-by-value where necessary.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2010/01/26/the-many-cases-of-byref.aspx

Comment: @SLaks: didn't find exactly the discussed case at the article, but: the article confirms that the perceivable semantics of `ByRef` is not the same as that of `ref`.

Comment: @Vlad: This is an example of `Don’t Copy Back ByRef`.  No. This behavior is at the call site; it's a difference between C# and VB.  The behavior will be the same whether you're pass a `ByRef` parameter or a `ref` parameter.

Comment: @SLaks: (1) Now I see the example, thanks. (2) The fact that the behaviour of call site is different is a pure implementation detail. The semantics of ByRef in VB consists of both how the function behaves and what the call statement is doing (this is true not only for this specific case, right? consider C++'s reference parameters, which are translated to a pointer by the call site). So the semantics is different. And this is the reason why replacing `ByRef` in VB code with `ref` in C# code didn't work. Would the semantics be the same, the problem wouldn't arise at all.

Comment: @Vlad: The semantics of the _argument_ aren't different; they both compile to identical IL.   If you pass a `ByRef` parameter in C#, you get C# semantics.

Comment: @SLaks: the IL is again an implementation detail, it's only the observable behaviour what defines the semantics.

Comment: The observable behaviors depends on the language of the callsite.

Comment: Exactly.  They depend on the language of the _callsite_, not of the function.

Comment: @SLaks: And this is basically what I am saying from the very beginning. The behaviour of `ByRef` in VB is different from the behaviour of `ref` in C#. Which exactly parts of the both languages are responsible for the difference--is the function different, or the call is generated in a different way--is not really relevant to the question (although is an interesting implementation detail).

Answer (score 1):

As long as I can remember, there has always been confusion about `ByVal` and `ByRef`/`ref` parameters. Here's the best way I can explain it:

You only need to pass an object by reference **if and only if** you plan on *replacing* that reference with a *different* reference. If you want to change the *contents* of the object being passed, you only need to pass it by value. Example:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
End Class

Public Shared Sub ModifyPerson(ByVal someone As Person)
    ' Passed by value          ^^^^^

    someone.LastName = "Doe"
End Sub

Public Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
    Dim me As New Person
    me.FirstName = "Adam"
    me.LastName = "Maras"

    ModifyPerson(me)

    Console.WriteLine(me.LastName) ' Writes "Doe"
End Sub
```

Yes, the instance of `Person` called `me` is passed into `ModifyPerson` **by value**; that just means the *reference* to the instance is passed by value. A function can still modify the members of that reference. Now, try this:

```
Public Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
    Dim me As New Person
    me.FirstName = "Adam"
    me.LastName = "Maras"

    AssignByValue(me)
    Console.WriteLine(me.LastName) ' Writes "Maras"

    AssignByReference(me)
    Console.WriteLine(me.LastName) ' Writes "Doe"
End Sub

Public Shared Sub AssignByValue(ByVal someone As Person)
    Dim new As New Person
    new.FirstName = "John"
    new.LastName = "Doe"

    someone = new
End Sub

Public Shared Sub AssignByReference(ByRef someone As Person)
    Dim new As New Person
    new.FirstName = "John"
    new.LastName = "Doe"

    someone = new
End Sub
```

These functions differ because they try to modify the actual reference being passed in. `AssignByValue` has no effect on the `Person` named `me` because the parameter is passed by value. However, `AssignByReference` can change the value of that parameter in the method that called it, hence why the second call to `Console.WriteLine(me.LastName)` reflects the updated reference.